# Create / Close Div in Array

Tags: terms, twitter-bootstrap

Found several similar questions, couldn't get anything to work. Trying to setup a bootstrap card that is created from array data. I am using the code below to create the divs if the array has data. The div is opened fine but am having trouble closing  . The code below generally "works" however the last item of the array is returned just outside  . Any help greatly appreciated.

```
<?php $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID , 'people' );

$len = count($terms);
$i = 0;

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

if ( $i == 0 ) {

    echo '<div class="card-header text-white bg-success"> Team 
     </div>
     <div class="card">
      <ul class="list-group"> '   ;
}

else if ( $i == $len - 1  ) {
    echo '</ul>  </div>' ;
}

$i ++ ;

echo ' <li class="list-group-item border-0"> 
            ' . $term->name . ' </li>  
     ';


}


?>
```

Jack Johansson answer was perfect. Below accomplishes the same goal using a foreach loop, may help someone else..

```
<?php

$the_page = sanitize_post( $GLOBALS['wp_the_query']->get_queried_object() );
$slug = $the_page->post_name;
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'research',
'posts_per_page' => '10',
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'researchcategory',
        'field' => 'name',
        'terms' => $the_page
        )
    )
);
$posts = new WP_Query( $args );
$posts = $posts->get_posts();

if (  $posts  && ! is_wp_error(  $posts ) ) { ?>

<div class="card mb-4 mt-4">
    <div class="card-header text-white bg-primary"> Research</div>
    <ul class="list-group">

        <?php
        foreach( $posts as $post ) { ?>
        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
            <?php echo esc_html( $term->name ) ?>

            <div class="title-meta">
                <?php add_filter( 'the_title', 'max_title_length'); ?>
                <?php echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">  '.get_the_title().'  </a>' ?>

                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <?php echo get_the_author(); ?> - <?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')).''; ?>
                </div>

                <?php  } ;  ?>  </li> </ul>  </div>   <?php   } ; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to count or do all the stuff to determine the last element. Check if the result of the function is valid, output the DIV and then inside that run a loop:

```
<?php

    // Get the terms
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'people' );

    // Check if there's any results, and there's no error.
    // If so, output the opening and closing DIV and UL
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) { ?>

        <div class="card-header text-white bg-success">Team</div>

        <div class="card">
            <ul class="list-group">
                <?php
                    // Now time to output the terms themselves
                    foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
                        <li class="list-group-item border-0">
                            <?php echo esc_html( $term->name ) ?>
                        </li><?php
                    }

                ?>
            </ul>
        </div><?php
    }

?>
```